# PowerShell script ask for password and use it to open excel files

Tags: excel, powershell

I would like to create script that will ask me for password then store it in memory and use to open Excel files.
Currently I have code that open excel files with password defined in script(part of code):

```
$password = "password"
$Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($currentExecutingPath2,0,0,5,$password,$password,$True)
```

Instead of this I am in need to use password entered at beginning of script.

I found out code that create variable:

```
$SecurePassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString
```

but it is not using my password in:

```
$Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($currentExecutingPath2,0,0,5,$Securepassword,$Securepassword,$True)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I assume (since your top example works) Excel expects a plain text password, but you are creating a SecureString that it doesn't understand.  What happens if you remove `-AsSecureString`?

Comment: Have you tried Get-Credential already? And then reference $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password

Comment: Hello,
I haven't tried Get-Credentiat but I suppose it should ask user for using his username and password. 

I will try with removing -AsSecureString :)

Comment: Thanks boxdog, 
It is working now :)